# Entity framework mapping issues

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-5

I am entirely new to .Net having been working in it for a week at most so please go easy and be detailed as possible :)

I have the following PONO:

```
Public Class WorkOrderEntity

    Private intTrackingNumber As Integer
    Private intDateReceived As Integer
    Private strManufacturer As String

    Public Property TrackingNumber() As Integer
        Get
            Return intTrackingNumber
        End Get

        Set(value As Integer)
            intTrackingNumber = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property DateReceived() As String
        Get
            ' TODO: Convert timestamp to formatted date
            Return intDateReceived
        End Get

        Set(value As String)
            ' TODO: Convert formatted date to timestamp
            intDateReceived = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

The issue I am faced with is how to store date/time as a timestamp (integer) but provide public properties which format/convert accordingly.

I suppose I could provide a an additional getter()/setter() but ideally I wonder if EF has a way of circumventing this "convention"?

Additionally - I am also curious as to whether it's possible to map properties to columns which are not labelled correctly?

Basically if I were working in a existing database (EF automatically builds my PONO with properties named after table fields) I wish to name the fields something more meaningful; some fields for example might be awkward abbreviations but in the object model I want something more English friendly?

I seem to recall being able to do this with Hibernate in Java (actually it's PHP port) but never the less does EF support such a feature?

Any ideas?

Comment: Plain Old Net Objects - it's a play on POJO :p

Comment: I just came up with that lol although i'm sure it's been thrown around before by others I assumed it would be obvious - as per usual my sense of humor has failed me :p my bad ;)

Comment: i did not heard about PONO, then i thought that is POCO, but PONO is not quite familiar.. `:D`

Answer (score 0):

A timestamp SQL Server at least is now a RowVersion. In either case it is not a datetime, but rather a byte array for the version which is auto updated when ever the row changes. You don't convert it to a date.

Regarding mapping an element via configuration rather than convention, you can use the attributes or fluent syntax to specify the mapping. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj200620 for info on how to use these features.